# MySQL foreign key on multiple columns?

Tags: mysql

I'm still learning MySQL, so please bear with me...

I have a few tables (outlined below) for which I would like to log error messages.  I'm not referring to query errors, but rather just my messages such as "connection to site failed", "card read error at site xyz", etc...

I was thinking of having a table "error_logs" to keep track of my errors with just three columns:

- id
- error_message
- is_active

The problem I'm encountering, however, is that each error would pertain to a record in the 'cards', 'doors', or 'sites' table and I would like to keep track of which record (from various tables) the message belongs to.

So, my question is what would be the best way to approach this?  I've considered adding two additional columns, 'record_id' (which would refer to an id in the other table) and 'table' (which would keep track of which table the message pertains to).  Also, another caveat, is that there will very likely be additional "primary" tables down the road.

Here are the tables I have thus far:

```
CREATE TABLE `statuses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$;

INSERT INTO statuses SET name = 'error';
INSERT INTO statuses SET name = 'pre-install';
INSERT INTO statuses SET name = 'validate';
INSERT INTO statuses SET name = 'active';
INSERT INTO statuses SET name = 'disabled';

CREATE TABLE `sites` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sites_status_id_idx` (`status_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sites_status_id` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `statuses` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$;

CREATE TABLE `doors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `doors_site_id_idx` (`site_id`),
  KEY `doors_status_id_idx` (`status_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `doors_status_id` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `statuses` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `doors_site_id` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `sites` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$;

CREATE TABLE `card_types` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sequance` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auth_code` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$;

CREATE TABLE `cards` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_oem` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `number_UNIQUE` (`number`),
  KEY `cards_type_id_idx` (`type_id`),
  KEY `cards_status_id_idx` (`status_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cards_status_id` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `statuses` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cards_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `card_types` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$;

CREATE TABLE `card_assignments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `door_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `card_assignments_door_id_idx` (`door_id`),
  KEY `card_assignments_status_id_idx` (`status_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `card_assignments_door_id` FOREIGN KEY (`door_id`) REFERENCES `doors` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `card_assignments_status_id` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `statuses` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your suggestion is perfectly valid. Just be sure to choose an `enum` 
data type for your `table_name` field; this way, the different table names get 
mapped to integer values transparently by `MySQL`. This will use less memory than a `VARCHAR` field 
and SELECTing errors related to a specific table will be faster. An additional 
`INDEX`/`KEY` over `table_name` 
**and** `record_id` will improve performance even further. You could create the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `error_logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table_name` enum('sites','tables','doors') CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `record_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `error_message` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `table_name` (`table_name`,`record_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

SELECTing errors by `table_name` would be as easy as:

```
SELECT * FROM error_logs WHERE table_name = 'sites'
```

When adding additional entities and tables as mentioned, remember to extend the `table_name` `enum` appropriately.

An **alternative** that I find somewhat inferior in your case would be to use separate id fields for each primary table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `error_logs2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cards_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doors_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sites_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `error_message` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cards_id` (`cards_id`),
  KEY `doors_id` (`doors_id`),
  KEY `sites_id` (`sites_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here, just one of the id fields would contain a value and the other two would be `NULL`. For inserting an error related to the sites table and record id 1:

```
INSERT INTO `error_logs2` (`id`, `cards_id`, `doors_id`, `sites_id`, `error_message`, `is_active`)
VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, '1', 'Exception has occurred: Division by zero.', '1')
```

SELECTing sites errors would work as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM error_logs2 WHERE sites_id IS NOT NULL
```

However, to be able to relate errors to a new entity you'd have to add a new column to the `error_logs2` table. However, selecting errors for one specific entity and id requires just one field comparison, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM error_logs2 WHERE cards_id = 5
```

Comment: Marcellus, many thanks for your input!  I will utilize your initial suggestion and create the table as you have outlined with the enum data type for the table column.  Thanks.